# make a Side Nav Bar using MaterialzeCss?

Tags: materialize

I am trying to make a Side Nav Bar using Materialize css, if anyone can guide me, I have try to follow the documentation in the website but I couldn't manage to do it, thank you .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//html code
 <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav full">

  <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>

  </ul>
</ul>


//js code
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
   $('.collapsible').collapsible();
});
```

Note:make sure you have loaded the required js files

Comment: What are the required js files?